# How can you create an object, set it exactly equal to another object, and modify it without affecting the old object inside of a loop?

Tags: java, loops, object

It's hard to explain what my problem is. All I want is to create a duplicate object and manipulate the new object without affecting the original object's data.

Let's say I have a class TicTacToe and I've created 2 objects, game1 and testField

```
TicTacToe game1 = new TicTacToe();
TicTacToe testField = new TicTacToe();
```

The class has multiple attributes, but here's the one being affected in this case

```
String[] gameField[9];
```

All I want to do is go into a for loop with the newly initialized object, set its 'gameField' to the 'gameField' of object "game1". Don't mind all the nonsense going on... Also, after each loop, it resets back to the "game1" object

```
            TicTacToe testField = new TicTacToe();
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {

                testField.gameField = game1.gameField;
                q = i+1;

                if (testField.gameField[i].equals("" + q))
                {
                    if (testField.humanStart) testField.gameField[i] = "O";
                    else testField.gameField[i] = "X";
                    game1.printField();
                    testField.printField();
                    if (testField.checkWin() == 2)
                    {
                        bestMove = "" + q;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem here is that BOTH objects are affected, even though it is supposed to be resetting.

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think you are talking about *defensive copies*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line `testField.gameField = game1.gameField;`

I think what you want to do is:

```
System.arraycopy( testField.gameField, 0, game1.gameField, 0, testField.gameField.length );
```

Alternatively, you could do:

`testField.gameField = game1.gameField.clone();`

Answer (score 0):

This is referred to as defensive copying. You have more details - [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15)

Also, you can create an object, but instead of merely assigning the object (in which case you assign the location of the original object to the new one), you can also create all individual elements and copy the values. This will create a new object and hence, not modify the original.

Comment: I understand exactly what you're saying and it would probably work, but I've tried the .clone() like what chsbellboy suggested and it worked!

Comment: I think essentially clone does the same thing too (internally).